# Drupal email when someone posts to forum topic

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, forums

Is there a module to email the owner of a post when someone replies to there forum post?

Answer (score 1):

Use Rules, and based on the fact that forum post is a node, and a comment is standard comment, define a rule that sends mail on comments of the forum content type.

If you need additional help, please let me know.

Comment: I would be interested to know how you would do this personally.

Comment: contact me via shushu.i@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I have used the drupal Notifications Module, which is the module used on groups.drupal.org to notify users of comment and content changes. http://drupal.org/project/notifications