# GoogleGroups-like Drupal Forum

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am looking for a tighter integration between forums and email. i wanted to setup my drupal instalation to:

- send an email to users when a new answer is posted to the topic
- create a new node when users answer by email (optionally, to a mailgroup)

what are the best modules to do this? how would i accomplish this?

Comment: reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868898/drupal-email-when-someone-posts-to-forum-topic made me aware of the possibility of using Rules and Notifications. this probably fixes my first question, leaving only part two: new posts on email answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of OG Mailinglist and would be happy to answer any questions you might have. It is in alpha still but it's quite stable and in daily use by a community of 4-500 people at island.byu.edu

Also, if you want to have a look over at the code, the latest is at http://github.com/KyleAMathews/og_mailinglist

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider using the  [OG Mailinglist](http://drupal.org/project/og_mailinglist) module, it is in alpha, but appears to do what you are looking for:

> OG Mailinglist allows users to start
>   new discussions by email and post
>   comments on existing discussions by
>   simply replying to emails. You get the
>   best of both worlds: a browser-based
>   discussion site and an email-based
>   list.

There is also [a good discussion here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/42688) about some alternative ways to do it.